# Error while running gremlin.bat file in Windows

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I downloaded the gremlin console zip file from apache tinkerpop website, unzipped the contents and tried running gremlin.bat command.
But I am getting this error "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Can someone please advise.
Thanks

Comment: what directory are you executing the gremlin.bat from?

Comment: from the bin folder

Comment: which version of TinkerPop are you using? did you try running it from the tinkerpop directory with `bin\gremlin.bat`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this behavior by setting `JAVA_ARGS` like this:

```
C:\opt\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.0\bin>set JAVA_ARGS=""

C:\opt\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.0\bin>gremlin.bat
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

If you unset the `JAVA_ARGS` variable, the Gremlin Console comes up as expected:

```
C:\opt\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.0\bin>set JAVA_ARGS=

C:\opt\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.0\bin>set JAVA_ARGS
Environment variable JAVA_ARGS not defined

C:\opt\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.0\bin>gremlin.bat

        \,,,/
        (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.3.0
```